# Socket.IO issue with event handler

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In my game, I'm trying to make it so that tiles are fetched once when the server connection is established, then every person that connects receives the tiles. Inside the useEffect is where the "join" event is supposed to fire. The "join" event handler doesn't seem to be working, though "disconnect" still does. Can someone help me figure out why this is?

index.js

```
io.on("connection", async socket => {
  console.log("New connection --------");
  const tiles = await getAllTiles();

  socket.on("join", ({ username, lobby }, callback) => {
    console.log("USER JOINED");
    const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, username, lobby });

    if (error) return callback(error);

    socket.join(user.lobby);

    io.to(user.lobby).emit("usersData", {
      lobby: user.lobby,
      users: getUsersInLobby(user.lobby)
    });

    socket.emit("tileData", {
      tiles: tiles
    });

    callback();
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected --------");
  });
});
```

React component

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { username, lobby } = queryString.parse(location.search);
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    socket.emit("join", { username, lobby }, error => {
      if (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? the "join" event on the server doesn't get fired?

Comment: @i.brod Yes that's correct, it doesn't seem to register the "join"event emitted from the client.

Comment: I don't use React hooks so i dont fully understand the useEffect function, but are you sure it's setup correctly? You need to create the connection only once. If it were a class based component, i would put it in componentDidMount, or even outside the component. Maybe explore what's going on in your "life cycle".

Comment: @i.brod My thinking is that the useEffect runs every time the query string parameters change i.e. someone new logs in. Then a new socket connection is created for this user and it emits a 'join' event to the server. I'll take a look into the life cycle but does what I'm trying to do sound correct to you?

Comment: Well i don't know how your application looks like, but in my experience a socket needs to be independent of all those little details, and created somewhere "Above". If  i had to build a frontend for a chat room, i would initialize the socket/chat room joining manually(like with some "join" button), not by some lifecycle. Don't think a socket needs to be affected by some React props, like the URL. Try to keep it as simple as possible, it's the best approach.